# Why did Willie Scott get on the plane with Indiana Jones?

Tags: movie, character-motivation, indiana-jones

In the beginning of the Temple of Doom, why wouldn't Willie just stay at the airport with Earl Weber? Maybe even go back to work for Lau Che?

She didn't steal the diamond, and Indy basically kidnapped her out of Club Obi Wan. Lau Che didn't seem to care if Indy hurt Willie (saying *"You keep the girl, I find another"*) and was shooting at their car, but also wouldn't seem to care if she went back to work either. Even Weber recognized her as *"Willie Scott the famous American female vocalist,"* so  she should be safe with Weber, and rushing out of town didn't seem necessary.

Did Willie have any reason to leave Shanghai, with just the clothes she was wearing, and stay with the guy who *"put two holes in her dress from Paris"* and who's gun *"burnt her fingers and cracked a nail?"*

Comment: I'm just rewatching the scene now. Lao Che seems to really enjoy his job. It's nice to see someone having a good time at work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The film's [Movie Storybook](https://archive.org/details/pdfy-i69Bxui39qgBWteZ) has a slightly different version of the scene but we can assume that her though process was much the same in the film.

- She willingly picked up the antidote, then left with Indy.
- Indy isn't dead, hence he must have the antidote.
- Lao Chan is shooting at her as well.
- She feels safer leaving Lao's immediate vicinity than she feels *unsafe* being with Indy on the rickety plane.

> Willie, though, had different concerns.
>   "Look what you've done to me." shee said. "My lipstick's smeared. I've broken two nails. I've got a run in my stocking—I'm a total mess!"
>   **"If Lao gets his hands on you after you let me get that antidote, you'll find out what being a mess really means,"** said Indy. And he pulled out a pistol to trade shots with the black sedan hot on their trail.
>   Pausing to reload his weapon, he said to the driver "Shorty! You call the airport?"
>   "Sure, Indy." said Short Round, not taking his eyes off the  Shanghai street maze he was zooming through, scattering cars, rickshaws, and pedestrians. "Got three seats—for you. me. and Wu Han."
>   "Wu Han's not coming' said Indy, wincing at the memory of his sidekick lying dead on the nightclub floor.
>   "Don't worry, Indy." Said Short Round. "Short Round number one bodyguard now."
>   **"We've got someone to use the ticket, though" said Indy.
>
>   "Me?' Willie protested. She heard a bullet whizz close past the window. "Me." she agreed.**
>   She didn't change her mind again until she saw the plane that was waiting at the airport.
>   "No way I travel on a cargo plane loaded with live chickens " she said. "I'm a star. I go first class"
>   "Suit yourself." said Indy. He grabbed his valise and ran with Short Round to the trimotor plane. Its propellers were already spinning.
>   **Willie took one quick look at the black sedan coming through the airport gate.
>
>   "Hey, wait up!" she shouted.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Indiana Jones: A Tale of High Adventure](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Temple_of_Doom:_A_Tale_of_High_Adventure)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's a good point, Indy's line in the car should've been in the movie. Lao Che was trying to kill Indy instead of keeping his word after all. There's also a [cut scene from behind the scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY59zQyjEdk) where Willie appears to say "Why you miserable little hood!" to Lao Che, and that's in scripts found online (but there's a lot of differences from the movie - like there's other passengers and the plane's attacked by a biplane...) The movie storybook has some minor differences but fills out some missing parts well.

Answer (score -2):

After Lao Che got his hands on the diamond, Indy threatened Willie again.  This time, Lao didn't give a rat's ass and told Indy that he could keep her.  I really cannot see Willie resuming her relationship with Lao after that.  And the moment Willie got her hands on the antidote, Indy clung to her like a leech.  He didn't even have the opportunity to take the antidote until they were in the car, on their way to the airport.

Comment: If Lao doesn't care then I could see her wanting to go back to work for him just to get paid, if nothing else. Especially given the time period & location I doubt many bosses cared about their employees a whole lot anyway. (PS I didn't downvote, but making it clearer why Willie would leave, or wouldn't want to leave, might make a better answer)